Inconsistency in numerical and slow-roll solutions of Mukhanov-Sasaki equation during Inflation
from my lectures in cosmological inflation, we derived the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation and its initial condition (Bunch-Davies). From here, it was of our interest to find a numerical solution of the equation to compare it with the slow-roll regime reults. So, according to my professor, we can write the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation in terms of $Q$, which he defined as the Mukhanov-Sasaki variable, such that $Q(t)=\delta\phi+\frac{\dot{\phi}}{H}\Psi$, and the perturbation of curvature, $\mathcal{R}=\frac{H}{\dot\phi}Q$. Then, we derived from a systen of equations that
\begin{align*}
\ddot{Q}+3H\dot{Q}-\frac{\nabla^2Q}{a^2}+\left(3\dot{\phi}^2-\frac{\dot{\phi}^4}{2H^2}+2\frac{\dot{\phi}V_\phi}{H}+V_{\phi\phi}\right)Q=0
\end{align*}
Then he said it's fine to just get
\begin{align*}
\ddot{Q}+3H\dot{Q}+\left(\frac{k^2}{a^2}+3\dot{\phi}^2-\frac{\dot{\phi}^4}{2H^2}+2\frac{\dot{\phi}V_\phi}{H}+V_{\phi\phi}\right)Q=0
\end{align*}
Notice everything is in cosmic time, which is how I want to calculate the numerical solution of this equation. Then, the professor introduced the equation in terms of $v_k$ in conformal time, and the initial condition
\begin{align*}
v_k=\lim_{k/aH>>1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}e^{-ik\eta}
\end{align*}
Taking $\eta$ as the conformal time. Using the relation that $v_k=aQ$, then $\dot{Q}=\frac{\dot{u}}{a}-Hu^2$ as long as $k>>aH$, which has to happen when $\eta\rightarrow-\infty$ or $t\rightarrow0$. Therefore, we have initial conditions since numerically we can find $\eta(t)$. With the solution, we can find the power spectrum $\mathcal{P_\mathcal{R}(k)}=\frac{k^3}{2\pi^2}|\mathcal{R}_k|^2$.
On the other hand, approximating the results with slow-roll regime indicates that $\mathcal{P_\mathcal{R}(k)}=\frac{H^4}{2\pi^2\dot{\phi}^2}\left(\frac{k}{aH}\right)^{-2\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2}$, where we can define $A_s=\frac{H^4}{2\pi^2\dot{\phi}^2}$, $n_s=1-2\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2=1-6\epsilon_V+2\eta_V$, with $\epsilon_V=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{V_\phi}{V}\right)^2$ and $\eta_{V}=\frac{V_{\phi\phi}}{V}$. Then, we just need initial conditions for $\phi$, $\dot{\phi}$, $a$ and $\eta$ and choose a potential $V$.
For this, I am using a single-field inflaton, with Starobinsky potential $V(\phi)=\frac{3}{4}\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\phi}\right)^2$, and knowing that $N_{\text{Tot}}=\int_{\phi_*}^{\phi_{\text{end}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$, but performing a reversion of the series we can get $\phi_*$. Taking $N_{\text{Tot}}=70$ and $\phi_{\text{end}}\approx0$, we get $\phi(0)=5.630991866033891$. Then, using slow-roll equations, $\dot{\phi}(0)=-0.008226306418212731$. Finally, since the inflation ends at some time when first $\ddot{a}=0$, the Hubble radii starts to increase, meaning $\eta(t_{\text{End}})=0$, and $t_{\text{End}}$ can be calculated numerically, being approximately equal to $150$. Therefore, we could try and normalize the scale factor to one at the end of inflation. However, after solving numerically the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation, the power spectrum at $k_{60}=a_{60}H_{60}$ (where $a_{60}H_{60}$ is evaluated at a time $t$ when $N_{60}=60$ from the end) differs completely from the slow-roll approximation. Nonetheless, this should not be the case, since both should be almost equal.
In a paper I was reading by Siddharth, S., et al. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.00529.pdf), they use the same potential and solve numerically the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation, and they found that the slow-roll approximation and numerical solution of the power spectrum are almost identical. Therefore, how is it possible that with the correct equations and logical initial conditions I cannot replicate the results? Are the equations wrong? Probably the initial conditions? What I have seen is that the initial condition of $a(t)$ is very susceptible to change the scales, but I cannot find a particular value that can match both analysis/results.

An image of the results of $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}(t)$ from slow-roll approximation. The numerical results shows values greater than $4\cdot10^6$, which cannot be compatible. Or the slow-roll model is wrong, or the numerical analysis is.
